# AWS EC2 with Nginx & PHP-FPM - Can not push CPU over 50%

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, kernel, php

I'm trying to test AWS Auto Scaling and for this I need to push an EC2 instance to a point where a trigger (say CPU above 80% for a few minutes) will induce another instance to be booted.

The catch I'm finding is a can't get the CPU above 50%.

I'm using Nginx and I have adjusted the number of worker_connections from 1024 up to much larger numbers. I have worker_processes set to auto. Also fastcgi_params is set as follows:

```
fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
```

I have php-fpm setup using dynamic an the following but I have also adjusted these numbers up a lot more without any real difference:

```
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_spare_servers = 50
```

I'm running siege and I can consistently get 1000 concurrent connections over 30 seconds with around 3500 replies and 100% (no dropouts) and no errors showing. I have also run 3 siege ec2 instance all with 1000 concurrent connections and found I sometimes get some socket errors but the the cpu never peaks over 50%. Often I find the outcome is still around 3500 replies just spread across the 3 servers (thus less replies each).

I have the php slow log on for 10seconds and there are a few queries in there so I put on a larger database (AWS RDS instance - largest possible with IOPS just to test) and this made no difference at all. I also put on a larger EC2 instance to see what would happen and the cpu would go above 50%.

Finally this my /etc/sysctl.conf

```
# Kernel sysctl configuration file for Red Hat Linux
#
# For binary values, 0 is disabled, 1 is enabled.  See sysctl(8) and
# sysctl.conf(5) for more details.

# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

# Controls source route verification
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

# Do not accept source routing
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

# Controls the System Request debugging functionality of the kernel
kernel.sysrq = 0

# Controls whether core dumps will append the PID to the core filename.
# Useful for debugging multi-threaded applications.
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1

# Controls the use of TCP syncookies
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

# Disable netfilter on bridges.
# net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
# net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
# net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0

# Controls the default maxmimum size of a mesage queue
kernel.msgmnb = 65536

# Controls the maximum size of a message, in bytes
kernel.msgmax = 65536

# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 4294967296

# Adam Added Below
kernel.pid_max = 262144
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
vm.max_map_count = 262144


# Do less swapping
fs.file-max = 2097152
vm.swappiness = 10
vm.dirty_ratio = 60
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 2


### GENERAL NETWORK SECURITY OPTIONS ###

# Number of times SYNACKs for passive TCP connection.
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2

# Allowed local port range
#net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 2000 65535

# Protect Against TCP Time-Wait
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1

# Decrease the time default value for tcp_fin_timeout connection
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15

# Decrease the time default value for connections to keep alive
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 300
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 15


### TUNING NETWORK PERFORMANCE ###

# Default Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_default = 31457280

# Maximum Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_max = 12582912

# Default Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_default = 31457280

# Maximum Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_max = 12582912

# Maximum Number of Packets
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 30000

# Increase the maximum total buffer-space allocatable
# This is measured in units of pages (4096 bytes)
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 65536 131072 262144
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 65536 131072 262144

# Increase the read-buffer space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 8192 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 16384
net.core.rmem_default = 131072
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216

# Increase the write-buffer-space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 8192 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 16384
net.core.wmem_default = 131072
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216

# Increase number of incoming connections
net.core.somaxconn = 32768

# Increase number of incoming connections backlog
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65536

# Increase the maximum amount of option memory buffers
net.core.optmem_max = 25165824

# Increase the tcp-time-wait buckets pool size to prevent simple DOS attacks
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
```

*** is there something that could be limiting the server to around 50% cpu usage? (memory is only every around 25% usage). I've never gotten the cpu to 55%.

I would like to be able to push the server to 90% + and then have another EC2 instance start. This way I'm really getting my money's worth from the server.

Any advise on why I would have this limitation and what I could try.

thankyou

Comment: http://blog.carlmercier.com/2012/01/05/ec2-is-basically-one-big-ripoff/ If you're not using very many of the AWS services, and can get by with your own database (rather than RDS), and you can organise your own scaling, then it's much more cost effective to avoid using amazon.

Comment: yer I did just read that... its a bit ugly... lol... I hear you on the cost effectiveness... I will consider it... thankyou

Comment: I've looked at dedicated for "base" load and EC2 for scaling. That works out significantly better financially. I've not had any luck finding scaling services (e.g: APIs) that deal with integrating dedicated servers with EC2 (or other cloud services). Stuck writing my own scaling code and external monitoring.

Comment: If you want to see your application use more CPU with a given workload, you need to test on a *smaller* instance, not a larger one... but exactly what value are you using to determine the 50% number you're reporting (how are you getting this value)?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to increase server load to trigger autoscale run the following command:

```
loadGen() { dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null & }; loadGen; read; killall dd
```

And to generate even more load (on multi-core machines), simply add more expressions between the pipes:

```
loadGen() { dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null & }; loadGen; read; killall dd
```

It will do the job.

[]s

Auro

Answer (score 0):

Use stress command

```
Stress -c 1
```

-c flag is for cpu numbers